# Flask - Get route URL from a function

Tags: python, flask

```
@app.route('/this/is/the/url')
def some_exposed_func():
    return render_template("data.html")
```

How to get '/this/is/the/url' from **some_exposed_func** handle?

```
print 'The func URL is: %s' % get_flask_route_url(some_exposed_func)
```

Comment: Ah, found my self: **url_for()** is the answer

Comment: It might be worthwhile to post an answer so that others who face similar problems can learn from the post

Comment: Sure, but I can't post the answer within 8 hours (?)

Comment: You can post it. You just can't accept it within (I think the limit is) 2 days

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found my self: **url_for()** is the answer

Comment: Here's a link to the relevant bit of the docs: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.url_for